# Как подсчитать два слова в одном столбце и вывести результат

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть столбец со строками в котором ставятся два значения (Да и Нет) эти значения у меня меняются динамически, хочу осуществить подсчет этих слов в конце таблицы и при этом если я поменяю значения то и вывод со словами тоже пересчитается. Как это сделать ? Может подскажите статью. Все это дело хочу провернуть на JS, Jquery

ДАанные таблицы хранятся в Базе данных
**data-id -** в ячейке означает номер строки
**data-name** - название столбца таблицы в бд
Механизм редактирования у меня следующим образом, если в строке таблицы присутствует класс Mult при клике на эту ячейку с классом я создаю Select option и выбираю значение. Как только я выбрал значения в столбце я хочу подсчитать сколько у меня вышло значений Да - Кол-во и Нет-Кол-во
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нашел что-то похожее что мне нужно [Пример](https://clck.ru/APFCt) тут идет подсчет всех слов, а мне нужно конкретные слова считать Да и Нет

Comment: Это всё отлично... а таблица-то где? в каком формате? откуда берёт данные и каков механизм их изменения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Написал пример на jQuery. Используется [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) — перебор элементов массива, и [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) — доступ к тексту внутри элемента

```js
var yes = 0
var no = 0
$('td.mult').each(function() {

  if ($(this).text() == 'Да') {
    yes++
  }
  if ($(this).text() == 'Нет') {
    no++
  }
})
document.write('Да: ' + yes + ' Нет: ' + no)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="mult">Да</td>
    <td class="mult">Нет</td>
    <td class="mult">Да</td>
    <td class="mult">Да</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: А как можно обновлять результат полученных значений ? Я просто таблицу редактирую динамически. И чтобы увидеть изменения по словам да или нет, приходится обновлять страницу, хотелось бы обойти это дело)

Comment: Да, конечно. Вместо `document.write` у вас будет что-то типа `$('div.myclass').text('Да: ' + yes + ' Нет: ' + no)`, а сам код поместите в функцию, которую вызывайте после внесения изменений.

Comment: спасибо все получилось так как и задумывал)